# How to tag all blank DOCPROPERTY fields?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to find and tag all blank DOCPROPERTY fields in a selection of text.

The macro will tag some of the required fields with the text, but not others.

The macro then fails with run-time error 5941.

I have a feeling it has something to do with how the loop is counting and cycling through blank fields.

```
Sub RemoveFieldCodes()

    'Moves to start of doc and selects text block
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=6, Extend:=wdExtend

    'Finds blank fields and appends text to end
    Dim i As Long
    With Selection
        For i = Selection.Fields.Count To 1 Step -1
            If .Fields(i).Type = wdFieldDocProperty And .Result = "" Then 
                .Fields(i).Select
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
                Selection.TypeText Text:="BLANK"
            End If
        Next i
    End With
```

Comment: You should be working with the `Range`, not the `Selection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work backwards through the collection; otherwise consecutive blanks are liable to be missed. Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  For i = .Fields.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Fields(i)
      If .Type = wdFieldDocProperty Then
        If .Result = " " Then
          Set Rng = .Result
          .Delete
          Rng.Text = "BLANK"
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It's not clear why you're using 'Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine' so, if:

```
          Rng.Text = "BLANK"
```

isn't sufficient, try replacing that with:

```
          With Rng
            .End = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End - 1
            .Text = "BLANK"
          End With
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!